# viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: is not called

Tags: ios8, xcode6, ios-app-extension

In my ios8 extension ActionViewController (subclass of UIViewController) 
viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: is not called when the device is rotated.
Should it not be ?
Do I need to do something ?

I'm using Xcode 6 beta 6 (6A280e) - beta 7 causes compile errors so I'm not using that yet.

Comment: did you every found the solution? Unfortunately I'm running into the same problem even after the final release

Comment: No, still doesn't work for me on ios8.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
But in my case, I found the events are always fired in initial view controller in storyboard correctly when the device rotated.
So I tell other objects the events from the view controller.
I hope this helps.